# Collecting elements from an enumerable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to collect an `IEnumerable<Item>` from a list of projects.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
IEnumerable<Project> projects;

List<Item> itemList = db.Items.ToList();
IEnumerable<Items> item = itemList.Where(i => i.ProjectID == /*the ID of each project from projects*/)
```

I also tried going this route: `IEnumerable<Items> item = from i in itemList where i.ProjectID == /*the ID of each project from projects*/ select i;`

How do I iterate through each project to collect all associated items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Items> item = from i in itemList
                          where projects.Any(p => p.ID == i.ProjectId)
                          select i;
```

or using your method syntax

```
IEnumerable<Items> item = itemList.Where(i => projects.Any(p => p.ID == i.ProjectID));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do that. Like those:

```
IEnumerable<Items> items = projects.SelectMany(p => itemsList.Where(i => i.ProjectID == p.ID))
```

or

```
IEnumerable<Items> items = itemsList.Where(i => projects.Any(p => p.ID == i.ProjectID))
```

Comment: Thanks for the different perspectives. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Any()`, you can also use the `join`:

```
var item = from i in itemList
    join p in projects on i.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
    select i;
```